# Is XSS Possible in this case?

Tags: javascript, php, security, lightbox

I'm not really good with security...So just wondering if in the event i was using lightbox 2.6.1 and i had

Edit: Example shows static, but in reality this google.com link comes from a mySQL DB which i have populated with links that goes along with the images (IE when users upload their image they key in a Image Link Source) so the Google.com is replace with that.

```
<a href="uploads/image.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" title="&lt;a target='_self' href='http://www.google.com'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;">
<img src="uploads/image.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
```

Would it be possible to execute a XSS or any form of dangerous javascript? I'm asking because i'm hesitant about this part.

```
title="&lt;a target='_self' href='http://www.google.com'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;"
```

Comment: Is that value coming from anywhere outside? (Otherwise asking about XSS would not make any sense.) And why are you setting such a strange title anyway …?

Comment: Actually yes, it's an image gallery for where users upload their images and tag their links. Clicking this caption link will bring the user back to the original link so yes, it is user-inputted from mySQL DB. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: What happens if you enter a double quote into the populated-title? So : `test"` does the double-quote get encoded to `&quot;`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "probably". It appears that HTML is being embedded within a "`title`" attribute of a HREF so make sure that you cannot break out of either

1. The `title` tag.
2. The embedded `href` tag

It all depends on what encoding you are using to insert values there but it may be tricky to ensure you are safe using encoding alone as you will also make sure that it is not possible to insert `javascript:` URLs.

Is there any validation you can perform on the URLs before they are inserted into your database? e.g. that the filename only contains alphanumeric characters and one dot before the extension.

See here for more info on preventing XSS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet